# Is there a way to emulate the <mark> tag with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I mean, is there a property that does essentialy this, other than `background-color`? I don't like to use HTML if the same thing can be done with CSS.

Comment: You can use CSS to get the visual effect of `<mark>`, but that is *just* `background-color`. You can't use CSS to give the semantic meaning it carries, that is what HTML is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but here is a solution:
make a css class, and call it however you like, lets say - "my_mark".

```
.my_mark{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

use is as a regular class and you got yourself a solution.