# Emulate mark tag with css for frequently changing selection

Tags: html, css, selection

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085321/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-the-mark-tag-with-css) what should answer my one, but which doens't because someone decided that `it's breaking semantic`. But I think there are some cases when it's neccessary.

I'm now writing a simple video player, which provied something like subtitles (something, becuase I receive them in custom binary format). I want to highlight some part of these subtitles (which are playing right now). Before I had several `span`'s and I dynamically added `active` class setting background to yellow. But it really looks ugly comparing to built-in `mark` tag.

The problem is that I should update subtitles several times per second, and so frequent modification of DOM generates serious UI laggs. Css `background` approach consumes zero resources, but looks ugly (spaces between words are not highlighted).

What is the best way to solve this problem?

My current markup is generated based on this binary subtitle info:

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.11" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.11)" class="active">You</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.36" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.36)" class="active">can</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.81" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.81)" class="active">always</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="4.01" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 4.01)">add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="4.26" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 4.26)">some</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.11" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.11)">non-breaking</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.22" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.22)">spaces</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.6" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.6)">before</a>
<p>
```

It changes a background of words:

```
.active[data-s2t-time] {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

But it doesn't look good:

[image]

If I use `mark` it looks fine:

[image]

But I get following markup:

```
<p>
    <mark>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.11" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.11)">You</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.36" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.36)">can</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="3.81" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 3.81)">always</a>
    </mark>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="4.01" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 4.01)">add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="4.26" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 4.26)">some</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.11" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.11)">non-breaking</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.22" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.22)">spaces</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-s2t-time="5.6" onclick="$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play', 5.6)">before</a>
<p>
```

Which is hard to modify (becuase I'm updating DOM itself instead of just setting some class to some elements)

I now ended with following css:

```
.active[data-s2t-time] {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    margin: -2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

But still looking for something better

Comment: Why should you update your subtitle a few times within a second? I don't think that is efficient

Comment: You can always add some non-breaking spaces `::before` and `::after` the span element... I'm not quite sure what the issue is, here. Why does it look ugly? What needs do you have besides the performance in regards to updates and frequency? Can you show us an example of what you've tried and what you do/don't like about your previous/current efforts????

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy because average pronouncing time for a word is 0.25 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using following CSS:

```
a.active[data-s2t-time], 
a.active[data-s2t-time]:hover, 
a.active[data-s2t-time]:focus {
    background-color: #019be3;
    margin: -2px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: white;
}
```